# ngbBootstrap DatePicker Configuration Set firstDayOfWeek

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to configure the ngbBootstrap datepicker to use Sunday as the first day of the week.  Seems like this should be super simple according to the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepickerConfig). I am using NgbBootstrap v1.1.2, but the documentation in code is the same as the current docs:

> Configuration service for the NgbDatepicker component. You can inject this service, typically in your root component, and customize the values of its properties in order to provide default values for all the datepickers used in the application.

```
import { NgbDatepickerConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  //...

  constructor(
    private ngbDatepickerConfig: NgbDatepickerConfig
  ) {
    ngbDatepickerConfig.firstDayOfWeek = 7;
  }

  //...
}
```

Any ideas why it's still set to Monday?

**Update**

Seems to work if I override the service defaults:

```
{
  provide: NgbDatepickerConfig,
  useClass: class Test {
    dayTemplate: TemplateRef<DayTemplateContext>;
    dayTemplateData: (date: NgbDateStruct, current: { year: number, month: number }) => any;
    footerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
    displayMonths = 1;
    firstDayOfWeek = 7;
    markDisabled: (date: NgbDateStruct, current: { year: number, month: number }) => boolean;
    minDate: NgbDateStruct;
    maxDate: NgbDateStruct;
    navigation: 'select' | 'arrows' | 'none' = 'select';
    outsideDays: 'visible' | 'collapsed' | 'hidden' = 'visible';
    showWeekdays = true;
    showWeekNumbers = false;
    startDate: { year: number, month: number };
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks right. What's the problem?

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, it's still set to Monday

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, maybe not. Post a complete example reproducing th eproblem, in a stackblitz. But there's a reason versions newer versions are released: they fix bugs. Staying on such an old version is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but it doesn't work on the root component when all the child components are lazy loaded.  I applied it to a common component used as a parent for all feature module route children and it works across the entire application as expected.

Answer (score 4):

My way to do is

1.-Create a class datePicker-config (it's a simple class of TypeScript)

```
import {NgbDatepickerConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class CustomDatePickerConfig extends NgbDatepickerConfig {
    firstDayOfWeek=3;
}
```

2.-Use this class in provider of NgbDatepickerConfig in your modules

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers:[{provide: NgbDatepickerConfig,useClass: CustomDatePickerConfig}]
  ...
})
```

Comment: Great way to handle common config in project